# I stuck the change methods.properly fetch JSON to normal method

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCrlL.jpg)

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    currentCategory: "",
    products: [],
    cart: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getProducts();
  }
  changeCategory = category => {
    this.setState({
      currentCategory: category.categoryName
    });
    this.getProducts(category.id);
  };

  getProducts = categoryId => {
    let url = "http://localhost:3000/products";
    if (categoryId) {
      url += "?categoryId=" + categoryId;
    }
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({
        products: data
      }));
  };
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    currentCategory: "",
    products: [],
    cart: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getProducts();
  }
  changeCategory = category => {
    this.setState({
      currentCategory: category.categoryName
    });
    this.getProducts(category.id);
  };

  getProducts = (categoryId) => {
    var item = db.products;
    console.log(item.categoryId);
    this.setState({
      products: item
    });

  }
}
```

/////Json format like shown below//////

```js
{
  "products": [{
    "id": 1,
    "categoryId": 1,
    "productName": "Chai",
    "quantityPerUnit": "48 - 6 oz jars",
    "unitPrice": 23,
    "unitsInStock": 53
  }],
  "categories": [{
    "id": "1",
    "categoryName": "Beverages",
    "seoUrl": "beverages"
  }]
}
```

in this first part work correctly when i fetch data from api. But when i wanna fetch json data from local its fine i can  but  not work properly as first method. At the first method filter products by `categoryId`  but i cant handle this filter.
`console.log(item.categoryId);` with this code i try to look can i get proper id's item on console but İ can see only undefined and if i use   `this.setState({products:item.categoryId});` then i take an error of about `map` function.

in this picture when i click one of category at the left side its filter the right side of products. İ can use this only first code i couldnt change properly.

Comment: So... you "can't handle" filtering by categoryId and you broke the program in protest?  You probably want to have > 1 product and > 1 category in your test data.   Suggested reading:  https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html , https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html , https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: where is db? var item = db.products  in json file or in the class itself?

Comment: actually as i said i can filtered  just try to change method

Comment: const db = require("./db.json"); db is here. And in getProducts method  var item = db.products i try to handle all

Comment: İn short. second json method not totally work as a first method